# Lotus C API example in Microsoft Visiual C++ Express

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have downloaded the Lotus C API Toolkit for Notes and Domino 8.5.2. On a Window7 64 bit pc I have installed the toolkit and Microsoft Visiual C++ Express.

When I try to run the example allflds.c I get these errors:

1>------ Build started: Project: test2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>allflds.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in notes0.obj
1>notesai0.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AddInMain@12 referenced in function _NotesMain@8
1>c:\users\zzz\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test2\Debug\test2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I have never worked with the Lotus C API before, pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I followed the settings mentioned in this document [DominoDefrag](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/0/24AC52AE04588804862577AD004039C3/%24File/DominoDefrag%20C%20API%20Visual%20Studio%20C++%202010%20Express%20Edition%2032bit%20Workstation%20Setup.pdf). Renaming

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

to

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC AddInMain(HMODULE hModule, int argc, char *argv[])
```

did the trick.

Comment: Nicely spotted: the domino notes0.obj contains a main already, hence the need to obfuscate the user-created main:)